# Compile app in Sunmi v2 with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have an application that is developed for SUNMI v1, but the client has changed to v2. They gave me a device to do the respective tests, but Android Studio does not recognize it. [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)) devices recognize it as `unauthorized`, but for the SUNMI v1 if it recognizes it, I kill and start the ADB server, but it still doesn't recognize the SUNMI v2.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Have you seen: https://docs.sunmi.com/en/docking-debugging/debugging-devices/

Comment: As I read the documentation you shared with me, I have to be registered as a partner beforehand, I thought it was like a phone that plugs in and compiles, thanks

Comment: SUNMI is the name of the company. What is "SUNMI v1"? What kind of product? What is the product name?